# ansible lineinfile module to match variable_value

Tags: search, ansible, replace

how can one possibly match value of a variable through regex parameter in lineinfile module?

```
- name: emptyline before search
  lineinfile:
    dest: ~/file
    insertbefore: '^{{ search_text }}$'
    line: ''
```

I tried above with both single/double quotes around, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: "It doesn't work" is rather unclear; what happens? Do you get an error message? Is it a task, a play etc.? Does the task finish with an "ok" (i.e. successful execution)? You should include more info. Also, what type of text is `{{ search_text }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a file `test.txt`

```
hello
something
test
hello
something
```

a run of a test playbook like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    BEFORE: "test"

  tasks:

  - name: Add line before
    lineinfile:
      path: test.txt
      insertbefore: '^{{ BEFORE }}$'
      line: ''
```

results into an output of

```
hello
something

test
hello
something
```

the expected one.